# Weird Install Issue with MySQL for PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

When using mysql_connect i get the error:
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
using Ubuntu
What's interesting is that php-mysql is installed. and the error when loading 
[Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vetkE.png)

Whats intersting here is the error of 
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli: **undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats**), /usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats)) in Unknown on line 0

again what does undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats means??!!!!

Thanks Everybody.

Comment: https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=+Unable+to+load+dynamic+library+%27mysqli%27&cat=web&pl=opensearch&language=english

Comment: i have no idea why anyone would down vote this question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason can be becasue you need to load mysqlnd before you load the mysqli extension.

Check your php.ini, php-mysqlnd needs to be loaded before other extensions..

Comment: But there is to problems with that, first ubuntu keeps selecting php-mysql instead if php-mysqlnd and i couldn't fix it,
second i don't have mysqlnd in any php.ini file in my system